# Inspired When West Winds Waft over me during my Long Walks

Tags: knowledge, no-computers

When West Winds Waft over me during my long Walks, become inspired Puzzle Maker. Where is this place?

I don’t have a profile yet, so it won’t help you much.

For those mathematically minded, they may not even need further clues, to find this beautiful place.

Some of the famous mathematicians worked here and their pioneering work forms the basis for new branches.

I made some simple words which includes all the letters found this place’s name.

Ice,  Cite,  Pot,  Not,  Inn,  Nor

Where is this place?

Name at least 3 famous people from here that had profound influence over several branches of mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> PRINCETON,

home of the

> Institute for Advanced Study, where many famous 20th-century mathematicians worked and made their breakthroughs,

as well as

> Princeton University, with alumni including **John Forbes Nash** and **Alan Turing**, and former professors including **Andrew Wiles**. Those famous enough names for you? :-)

Comment: Got it..name a few of the for complete answer sake.

Comment: @Uvc Done. (For the record, "place that produced many world-famous mathematicians" cuts it down to very few possibilities. My first thought was Gottinger, which didn't work, but a lot of the Gottingen guys relocated to [the correct answer].)

Comment: Yes..most famous scientist used to give guest lectures at this place founded 260 years. Ago.

Comment: A Beautiful Mind.

Comment: Is there any significance to the bizarre capitalization of the W words in the title and puzzle?

Comment: Dunno, Rubio. @Uvc?

Comment: Not really..just wanted to highlight w.

Comment: @Uvc When you do something unusual/unexpected in this type of puzzle, people will take it as a hint. Any stylistic choice can be used as a hint: italics, capitalisation, particular words used, ...

Comment: Well taken..will avoid in future.